# Delete a snapshot from cassandra

Tags: linux, cassandra

I'm running a 4-node Cassandra cluster. Some of our nodes have some very large snapshots, and we're running out of disk space. I need to delete the snapshots, but I can't find any documentation which states how to do this properly. Do I just shut the node down and delete the files in the snapshots directory? Is there some kind of command? Thanks.

Comment: i think this question is much suited for cassandra mailing list or IRC. You will get a quick/better reply. http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=#cassandra

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK I figured this one out (with the help of IRC). It's `nodetool -h localhost clearsnapshot`.

Comment: Just note that clearsnapshots clears ALL snapshots. If you want to be more selective (e.g. keep a couple of days' worth) you can apparently safely delete snapshots directly from the snapshots folder.